# Iterator for traversing a tree

Tags: c++, tree, iterator, c++17

What I want to achieve is the following:

```cpp
#include "tree.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() {

  Tree<std::string>* tA = new Tree<std::string>("A");
  Tree<std::string>* tB = new Tree<std::string>("B", tA);
  Tree<std::string>* tC = new Tree<std::string>("C", tA);
  Tree<std::string>* tD = new Tree<std::string>("D", tB);
  Tree<std::string>* tE = new Tree<std::string>("E", tB);
  Tree<std::string>* tF = new Tree<std::string>("F", tB);

  for (auto cur : *tA) {
    std::cout << "traversed from " << (cur->parent ? cur->parent->val : "NULL") << " to " << cur->val <<  std::endl;
  }

  // std::next(std::next(tF->begin()));

  return 0;
}
```

And here is my implementation.

```cpp
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

#include <iterator>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Tree {
 public:
  class iterator {
   public:
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = T*;
    using reference = T&;

   public:
    iterator() = default;

    iterator(Tree<T>* const root);

    Tree<T>* operator*() const;

    iterator& operator++();

    bool operator!=(iterator const& other) const;

    Tree<T>* cur;

   private:
    std::stack<Tree<T>*> s_;
  };

 public:
  Tree() = default;

  Tree(T const& val, Tree<T>* parent = NULL);

  void* operator new(size_t size);

  iterator begin();

  iterator end();

  T val;

  Tree<T>* const parent = NULL;

 private:
  std::vector<Tree<T>*> children_;
};


template <typename T>
Tree<T>::iterator::iterator(Tree<T>* const root)
    : cur(root) {}

template <typename T>
Tree<T>* Tree<T>::iterator::operator*() const {
  return cur;
}

template <typename T>
typename Tree<T>::iterator& Tree<T>::iterator::operator++() {
  if (cur == NULL) {
    throw std::out_of_range("No more nodes for traversal");
  }

  for (auto& child : cur->children_) {
    s_.push(child);
  }

  if (s_.empty()) {
    cur = NULL;
  } else {
    cur = s_.top(); s_.pop();
  }

  return *this;
}

template <typename T>
bool Tree<T>::iterator::operator!=(Tree<T>::iterator const& other) const {
  return cur != other.cur;
}

template <typename T>
Tree<T>::Tree(T const& val, Tree<T>* const parent)
    : val(val), parent(parent) {
  if (parent) {
    parent->children_.push_back(this);
  }
}

template <typename T>
void* Tree<T>::operator new(size_t size) {
  void* p = ::new Tree<T>();
  return p;
}

template <typename T>
typename Tree<T>::iterator Tree<T>::begin() {
  return iterator(this);
}

template <typename T>
typename Tree<T>::iterator Tree<T>::end() {
  return iterator();
}

#endif
```

User should be able to directly modify `val` (hence it is public). However, they shouldn't be able to modify any parent/children relationship. Therefore I try to make `parent` a `const` pointer, but I cannot make `children` a list of `const` pointers because anything inside a `std::vector` must be assignable. I am considering exposing a `GetChildren()` method which returns a `const std::vector`, but that would be inconsistent with how I dealt with `parent`. Can anyone show a good way to resolve this?

General reviews are welcome. More specifically, I want to know

1. Is this a good and correct use of pointers?
2. Is the interface well designed?
3. Are there any `const` that I missed?

Comment: Does this code work as expected?

Comment: Yes, I am able to compile and run it. Is there something wrong?

Comment: What kind of tree (binary, B, B*) tree is this supposed to work for?

Comment: I am able to compile using the command `g++ main.cc -o tree -std=c++17 -Wall -static -O3 -m64 -lm`. This is a general tree (can have multiple children).

Comment: It was my compiler, needed to be upgraded.

Comment: Just curious: why all this heap and pointers?

Comment: Because I do not want to make any copy... is this reason justified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Clean up allocated memory (everything `new`ed should be `delete`d), or use smart pointers to do it for you. (Perhaps each tree node should own its children, and store them in `unique_ptr`s, and the parent should be a raw pointer).
- There doesn't seem to be any benefit to overloading `operator new` for the `Tree` class.
- Currently, the iterator is more of a sub-tree iterator, as it never returns to the parent. e.g. for a tree with edges: A->B->C and A->D if you start iterating at B, you will only iterate from B to C, and never reach D.
- Iterators are normally defined outside of the corresponding container class. We can use an `iterator` `typedef` in the container to refer to the iterator class.
- `operator*` should return a reference, not a pointer (`operator->` should return a pointer).
- We have `!=`, but no `==`.
- We have a pre-increment `operator++`, but not post-increment `operator++`.
- It would probably be best to write unit tests for things that are expected to work, e.g.: `*i` (returns a modifiable reference), `*i++` (returns a modifiable reference and then increments i to point at the next value), etc. This can be tedious, but is really the only way to ensure correctness.
- The full [requirements for a forward iterator are listed here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) (and in the linked pages), and many of them could be translated into tests cases. This iterator should arguably be a bidirectional iterator.
- Standard containers also supply a `const_iterator` version (and reverse iterators, though that's usually simple to add).

To be honest, I'd suggest starting with something a bit simpler like an array class, and corresponding iterators.

---

Note that we can traverse a tree in many different ways (depth-first in-order, depth-first pre-order, depth-first post-order, breadth-first). For a full-featured implementation of this sort of thing, see the [ASL Forest class](https://stlab.adobe.com/group__asl__tutorials__forest.html).

Since we're iterating nodes, not values, we don't have to worry about "order", but we should still call the class something like `tree_depth_first_iterator`, to distinguish it from the alternative(s).

---

Comment: What about the use of NULL versus nullptr?

Comment: I think since C++11 we should really just use `nullptr`. My reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr/19014644#19014644